# pygame text variables

Tags: python, variables, text, fonts, pygame

I'm having trouble with pygame...again...one of these days I swear I'll be good enough to not have to come here for easy answers...

Anyway, the problem this time is I'm trying to print text on the screen with a variable inside it.

```
wordfont = pygame.font.SysFont("sans",12)

class Status:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a=30

    def showme(self):
        health = wordfont.render(("Your health: ", self.a,), 1, (255, 9, 12))
        screen.blit(health, (150, 150))
```

It says that it has to be a string or unicode...but maybe there is some way? Once again, I remind everyone to not correct anything that I'm not asking about. I know there is probably some easier way to do these things...

Comment: I realy recommend you not use a variable that's not in the function, I know it's possible but avoid using these, some times it makes problems that you never even thought it can make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
health = wordfont.render(("Your health: ", self.a,), 1, (255, 9, 12))
```

Should be

```
health = wordfont.render("Your health: {0}".format(self.a), 1, (255, 9, 12))
```

or

```
health = wordfont.render("Your health: %s" % self.a), 1, (255, 9, 12))
```

`("Your health: ", self.a,)` is a tuple. By passing a string, you can solve your problem.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to understand what I have done...

Comment: @user2154113 Well, if you want to learn, you better understand what you did wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `tuple` `("Your health: ", self.a,)` as the first argument to `render`. I'm assuming there should be a string instead.

There are several ways [to format a string with a variable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), one approach is this:

```
msg = "Your health: {0}".format(self.a)
health = wordfont.render(msg, 1, (255, 9, 12))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to send a string instead of a tuple to render as first argument:

```
health = wordfont.render("Your health: " + str(self.a), 1, (255, 9, 12))
```